# How do you reference MS office interops in C#?

Tags: c#, office-interop

I am trying to access Outlook 2007 from C#.  I have installed the PIA msi after following the directions found on msdn.  After a successful install nothing shows up in Visual Studio's references under the .net tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Office interaction is available through COM objects found on the 'COM' tab of the 'Add Reference' dialog window.

Answer (score 0):

After you downloaded the installer and ran it, did you run the MSI installer it extracted and placed in the folder it asked you to create?